# Trying to find $f(x)\in F[x]$ such that $f(A)=A^{-1}$ 

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an invertible $3\times 3$ matrix:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\  
1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$

I am trying to find $f(x)$ from  $F[x]$ such that $A^{-1}=f(A)$.  To do so, I want to use the result of [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29158), which says that $f(A)$ is invertible if and only if $f$ and the minimal polynomial of $A$ are relatively prime.

Comment: What is $F[x]$?

Comment: polynomials vector space from any field F.

Comment: Ah. To make that clear you should probably say $f(x)\in F[x]$ and state that $F$ is the field you are working over; I thought you meant derive $f(x)$ from some polynomial $F[x]$ you are given.

Comment: "Hey," is the sort of thing you yell at someone on the street to catch their attention. Have you considered some more pleasant greeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following two facts:

- Every square matrix is a zero of its characteristic polynomial.
- The constant term of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is its determinant.

Combining these two things you can write the characteristic polynomial $c_A(x) = x \cdot p(x) + det(A)$. From this, you can see that the polynomial

$f(x) = -\frac{1}{det(A)}p(x)$

has the desired property (since $c_A(A)=0$ implies that $A \cdot p(A) = - det(A)$.)

Answer (score 1):

in general if you have the minimal polynomial $p_A(X)=X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+...+a_0$ (i.e. irreducible with $p_A(A)=0$), then $$A^{-1}=(-1/a_0)(A^{n-1}+a_{n-1}A^{n-2}+...+a_1).$$ so $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A$.  this comes up in linear algebra, field theory (if you want the inverse of some algebraic element $\alpha$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$), etc

Answer (score 1):

Let $p\in F[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of any square matrix $A$ with entries in $F$, and let $f=p_1/p_2\in F(x)$ (with $p_i\in F[x],p_2\neq0$) be a rational fraction. Assume that $p$ is prime to $p_2$, so that $f(A)$ is well defined.

Then there is a unique $r\in F[x]$ of degree less than $\deg p$ such that $f(A)=r(A)$. Moreover $r$ is given by the following simple formula.

We can assume, by enlarging $F$, that $p$ splits over $F$ as
$$
p=\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\ (x-\lambda)^{m(\lambda)}
$$
with $m(\lambda) > 0$ for all $\lambda$. Then we have
$$
r=\sum_{\lambda\in \Lambda}\ T_\lambda\left(\frac{(x-\lambda)^{m(\lambda)}}{p}T_\lambda(f)\right)\frac{p}{(x-\lambda)^{m(\lambda)}}\quad,
$$
where $T_\lambda(g)$ means "order less than $m(\lambda)$ Taylor polynomial of $g$ at $\lambda$".

Note that $T_\lambda(f)$ exists because $f$ is defined at $\lambda\in\Lambda$ thanks to the assumption that $p$ is prime to $p_2$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ \ 0\ =\ f(x)\ =\ a + x\ g(x)\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ x\ (-g(x)/a)\ =\ 1\ $ if $\rm\ a_0 \ne 0\:,\ $ e.g. $\rm\: f(x) = $ min. polynomial.

I.e. exploit the the fact that the "ring of linear operators" $\rm\: F[A] \cong F[x]/f(x)\ $  where $\rm\:f(x)\:$ is the minimum polynomial of $\rm\:A\:$ over $\rm\:F\:.$ Note that this depends crucially on the fact that the coefficients commute with $\rm\:A\:,\:$ being scalars $\rm\in F\:.$

This is just the special case $\rm\ h = x\ $ of $\rm\ (f,h) = 1\ \Rightarrow\ h^{-1} $ exists $\rm\:(mod\ f)\:$, and is computable by the extended Euclidean algorithm, since $\rm\:F[x]\:$ is a Euclidean domain. This is frequently used for the purposed of [rationalizing denominators](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/522d8e8b00ab0617)  in algebraic extension fields.

More generally, one can use the same "operator" techniques to compute inverses modulo "constant" coefficient differential / difference (recurrence) operators. They are all abstractly isomorphic to working in a polynomial ring residue field $\rm\:F[x]/f(x)\:.$